# c (and objc, and c++ and objc++) - char* argv[]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, argv

I create a clone of the echo command and that's more complicated than I was thinking.
Here my problem :
How works a char *argv[]? I know how works char myString[], but no that weird way to create strings :

- It's a pointer on an array of chars, or an array of pointers on chars?
- Why when I *argv[n], it shows me the n argument, not the n char... Chars can ve

Comment: cout << argv[n] -> it should print nth argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char* argv[]` behaves just like `char** argv` would behave. You could also use an `char argv[][]` the same way.

So basically, when you call `*argv`, you get `argv[0]` and `*argv[n]` gives you `argv[0][n]`

edit: to convert `argv[x]` into a `std::string`:

```
std::string s(argv[x]);
```

from that point on s is a standard string. But keep in mind that you must have zero terminated strings, this will not work for random binary data in a `char**`!

Comment: So, how have the size of a specific argument?

Comment: @sosolal you want to get the size of a specific string in the argv[]? you could iterate over argv[x] until argv[x][i] == '\0', then the string is over.

Comment: How complicate stuff for nothing... I will try that.

Comment: @sosolal if you want it faster, safer etc I'd recommend you to use the [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) in c++. It has a method `length()` that returns exactly the length of the string.

Comment: How convert char*[] in strings?

Comment: Thanks. I will test with a queue<string>.

Comment: @sosolal if your question is answered, make sure to accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

> It's a pointer on an array of chars, or an array of pointers on chars?

In C, arrays are always passed as pointer to the first element. So, effectively you can treat it as char**, which is a pointer to pointer of char.

> Why when I *argv[n], it shows me the n argument, not the n char... Chars can ve

You can split that expression according to the [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence):

```
char* p = argv[n];
char  c = *p;
```